# How to display and shut message modal when hovering over buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to display a text description box when I hover over the button and close it when not hovered. At the moment, when my button is hovered the text box displays, however I need to click off the screen to close it. When I try to use several buttons to show different message boxes, all the modals are opened and I need to click the screen many times to close it. How can I show the message box on hover and undisplay when the mouse is not hovered over. How can this be achieve for multiple buttons?

Below is what i have so far:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#test1").hover(
        function () {
            $('.modal').modal({
                show: true
            });
        },
        function () {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
        });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<button class="btn login btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product1" id="test1">Test</button>
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      This text box shown when mouse hover over the button
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First major problem: when bootstrap displays this modal, it overwrites everything on the web page, including the Test button, which makes it out of reach of a mouseOut (the bottom of the modal dialog is over the button )

This is solved by bidding on the order of the display layers by placing a larger z-index css (I put 8000 and this also works only if the element uses a positioning)
As a result, this is no longer a true modal dialog, and the click on the Test button can be triggered, which is contrary to the spirit of using a modal dialog.

the BS4 doc on the subject => https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#via-data-attributes

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  "use strict";
  
  $(".BtModals").hover(
    function () {
      let refID = '#' + $(this).data('modal_id');
      $(refID).modal('show');
    },
    function () {
      let refID = '#' + $(this).data('modal_id');
      $(refID).modal('hide');
    });
});
```

```css
.BtModals:hover {
  position:relative;
  z-index: 8000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
  integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous">
</script>

 <button class="btn login btn-primary BtModals" data-modal_id="Modal-t1"  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product1" >Test 1</button>

  <button class="btn login btn-primary BtModals" data-modal_id="Modal-t2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#product1" >Test 2</button>


  <div id="Modal-t1" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      This text box shown when mouse hover over the button  Test 1
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="Modal-t2" class="modal fade bs-example-modal-sm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="mySmallModalLabel"
  aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
    <div class="modal-content">
      This text box shown when mouse hover over the button  Test 2
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks  @MrJ  , this works well . but there is an issue , when i try to make multiple of them and give description for each and Hover over the button . it merges the texts from all modal contents . also i cant use the same id  id="test1" so i have to change that for every button. does that mean i need to make a script for each ?

Comment: no, you can use a class instead the ID, and use data attribute to select the concerned modal on his ID.

Comment: I made the change for multi-Buttons / modals on this answer

Comment: Thank you @MrJ , that seems to work well now. thanks for all your help, it is well appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

New Answer:

**"hover"** method accepts second argument as handlerOut.

So you can do something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    "use strict";
    $("#test1").hover(
        function () {
            $('.modal').modal({
                show: true
            });
        },
        function () {
            $('.modal').modal('hide');
        });
});
```

---

Old Answer:

Since you use bootstrap, for such cases, you can use popover.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#popovers-examples

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">Tooltip on left</button>
```

Comment: your solution doesn't quite work . when i move the mouse off the button the text doesn't disappear. also  if i want to use multiple button what do i do. at the moment it opens all the modals  when i do it. and i have to click the screen several times to close them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with CSS by setting a data attribute with the 'hover text' in the HTML for each button. If there are too many buttons to do it manually, or if they change dynamically, you can loop over them in JS and use `.setAttribute("data-tip", "tip_content")`.

Here is an example of the HMTL and CSS:

```
<button data-tip="Show this on hover">My botton</button>
```

```
button:hover:after {
    content: attr(data-tip);
    color: red;   
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
}
```

Here is the codepen link if you want to see it live: https://codepen.io/CPC464/pen/KEbJJo

Comment: again thats like bootstrap tooltip/ pullover , it writes it in 1 line .  this doesn't suit the purpose.  i have list  of " products" and i am trying to provide each of which a button (view more)  with a text box to show the description of the product when the button is hovered.

Comment: Not sure I understand what it is you are trying to achieve then? (@Nick - thanks for the format edit)